# Airflow dag automatically Triggers

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have created the dag with the following configuration

```
job_type='daily'
SOURCE_PATH='/home/ubuntu/daily_data'

with DAG(
    dag_id="transformer_daily_v1",
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    description="transformer to insert data",
    start_date=datetime(2022,9,20),
    schedule_interval='31 12 * * *',
    catchup=False
) as dag:
    task1=PythonOperator(
        task_id="dag_task_1",
        python_callable=get_to_know_details(job_type,SOURCE_PATH),
    )

def get_to_know_details(job_type,SOURCE_PATH):
     print("************************",job_type,SOURCE_PATH)
```

Each time when i start the airflow using command

```
airflow standalone
```

the dag function executed automatically without Triggering as seen in the logs

```
standalone | Starting Airflow Standalone
standalone | Checking database is initialized
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
WARNI [airflow.models.crypto] empty cryptography key - values will not be stored encrypted.
************************ daily /home/ubuntu/daily_data
WARNI [unusual_prefix_8fc9338bb4cf0c5518fed57dffa1a11abec44c36_example_kubernetes_executor] The example_kubernetes_executor examp
le DAG requires the kubernetes provider. Please install it with: pip install apache-airflow[cncf.kubernetes]
```

airflow version - 2.2.5

Comment: but you have scehdule it. I think you can use ```schedule_interval=None```

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte its fine when its triggers at schedule interval but the thing is that when i start the aiflow with 'airflow standalone ` command its first triggers the dag function even when the schedule intervel is set for the future time interval for e.g now the time is 10:30 and i set the cron expression 45 11 * * *  now when i start the airflow the dag function triggres automatically and after completing the dag fucntion the airflow start its webserver and all left initializing things.